# How can I make dynamically generated getter and setters known to TypeScript's compiler?

Tags: javascript, typescript, getter-setter

The following code works without any errors in JavaScript:

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "hello", {
            get() {return "world!"}
        })
    }
}

let greet = new Test()
console.log(greet.hello)
```

But TypeScript throws this error:

`Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'Test'.`

**Update**

This is similar to what I need and I was trying. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2J4CcAKYQFMAu3PQG8AoaU6AYmERRgF5oBtEslhgIgDMVMBzZeAK4A7ACYIkyNgBpobSsAUK2AXRnMWpdgCMwwANZ9Bo8SmmzyAZivWVajWW0oRmZCcky5YL95XroygG5oIj8qIQhsZAFgbBQACgBKQj8WbAALAEsIADpKamQcrmQAUV00uLjMGQyk2gA%20ZPt7AHktACtMGOznDgyhTFR%20AAcXbABPOPSsmSmcvIkIBgzlBgAGVUamrcwhAQBbFzAtLAAuaEiBKpStsh4cRMJoZBwBZCFzzLmqBaWVgEZAtAAL5Sa43aAQe5pTAADzOEWQfR4SQIwXB4IyHGgcQA9AA9chrAC0AE4wESOMoCAA2IEAEhxGWyeAicWhMISKLR6J5s1y3xovwYAOg9HZATBPOBkq2QJlZCBCUliolLDlfliAGVIkjEvCdUIeJt7M9sK93q0Ol0AG4YS4QSafBLZPZgIZxYCihrAZnwbWIw2JX0AVSGI1ckEwiWdbXgfTiZjYCVVCqI6qw2CemBE6AzeFF0H6AHc4Plczg8IkJTicVmcxgK5hskVePxhGJ8gW5BwOKs%206s2EFoAAeIljsfQFz8ZBnNiDeDh8bQADkLcM7bcy%20gIngmBgQngmdhWUz8He4xGK7c5dwmGXbGCYQgiCbSB4cWe9bzTa1BvfnICIA).
I want compile time check for properties becasue they might change in future.

```
class ColorPalette {
    #colors = [
        ["foregroundColor", "#cccccc"], 
        ["backgroundColor", "#333333"], 
        ["borderColor", "#aaaaaa"]
    ]; 

    constructor() {
        this.#colors.forEach((e, i) => {
            Object.defineProperty(this, this.#colors[i][0], {
                enumerable: true,
                get() { return this.#colors[i][1]; },
                set(hex: string) { 
                    if (/^#[0-9a-f]{6}$/i.test(hex)) { 
                        this.#colors[i][1] = hex;
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    }

    toString(): string {
        return Object.values(this).map(c => c.toString().toUpperCase()).join(", ");
    }
}
let redPalette = new ColorPalette();
// redPalette.foregroundColor = "#ff0000";  <----- error: "Property 'foregroundColor' does not exist on type 'ColorPalette'" 
console.log(redPalette.toString());
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that for dynamically generated things; TS would then have to run your code to figure out how they mutate the objects, and that's not going to happen. What's your actual use case for dynamic getters/setters?

Comment: @AKX, I have a class with lots of properties of the same type, so they need the same validation logic. In another words, only the names and values are different. I was trying to save some typing and reduce the repetitive work.

Comment: Unfortunately if you want compile-time type safety for them, then you'll need to spell them out somehow in the code. One option would be, of course, to generate the .ts code required instead of typing it out manually.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjJo7w) meet your needs?  It's got two approaches: one is (like @AKX says), whatever's dynamically generating your getters should dynamically generate your class property declarations also; the other is that you write a function that produces a class constructor from an object of getters and is strongly typed so you can use it later.  Let me know if you want either or both of those written up as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz, I am already writing TS which obviously compiles to JS and then using the JS files to generate some JSON and Markdown files. I rather not to add another step to that. I think I am more interested in the second approach, even though it has a complicated code and harder to understand for me.

Comment: Oh I thought by "generated" in your question, you were talking about code generation, but I guess you're not doing that.  I'm happy to write up an answer explaining what's going wrong with your code and the possible class factory function approach, but could you expand your question code to a [mcve] that shows "lots of properties of the same type, so they need the same validation logic"?  Maybe not "lots", but at least two or three to give the general idea.  If they need to access `this` then your example should do that too. If they do validation then a toy validation would also help.

Comment: The idea is so that I can make sure a potential answer matches your use cases before posting it.  For example [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NrvY3N) should now make it possible to access the `this` context inside the getter methods passed in, but I don't know if that's what you need or want.

Comment: @jcalz, Thanks, I have updated the question with a sample code .

Comment: Thanks so much for the [mcve].  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPj2JN) work for your use case?  I'm using a class factory function which turns an object holding property descriptors into a class with those properties.  If it works for you I'll write up the answer explaining how it works.  Otherwise, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz, Yes that works perfectly for my use case. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things standing in the way of your code working as-is.

The first is that you cannot declare class fields implicitly inside the `constructor` method body in TypeScript code.  If you want a class to have a property, you will need to explicitly declare this property outside the constructor:

```
class ColorPalette {
    foregroundColor: string; // <-- must be here
    backgroundColor: string; // <-- must be here
    borderColor: string; // <-- must be here
// ...
```

There's a declined suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#766](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/766) asking for such in-constructor declarations, and an open-but-inactive suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#12613](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12613) asking for the same, but for the foreseeable future, it's not part of the language.

The second problem is that, in TypeScript code, calling `Object.defineProperty()` in a constructor does not convince the compiler that the property in question is [definitely assigned](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization), so when you use the `--strict` compiler option, you'd need something like a [definite assignment assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) to quiet the warnings:

```
class ColorPalette {
    foregroundColor!: string; // declared and asserted
    backgroundColor!: string; // ditto
    borderColor!: string; // ditto
// ...
```

There's a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#42919](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42919) for the compiler to recognize `Object.defineProperty()` as initializing properties, but for now, it's also not part of the language.

If you're willing to write the name and type of each property twice, then you can get your code to work way you originally had it.  If you aren't, then you need to do something else.

---

One possible way forward is to make a class *factory function* that produces class constructors from some input.  You put some property descriptors (well, functions that return such descriptors) into the function, and out comes a class constructor which sets those properties.  It could look like this:

```
function ClassFromDescriptorFactories<T extends object>(descriptors: ThisType<T> &
    { [K in keyof T]: (this: T) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T[K]> }): new () => T {
    return class {
        constructor() {
            let k: keyof T;
            for (k in descriptors) {
                Object.defineProperty(this, k, (descriptors as any)[k].call(this))
            }
        }
    } as any;
}
```

The call signature means: for any generic `T` of an object type, you can pass in a `descriptors` object whose keys are from `T`, and whose properties are zero-arg functions that produce property descriptors for each property from `T`; and what comes out of the factory function has a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that produces instances of type `T`.

The `ThisType<T>` is not necessary, but helps with inference in the case where you are defining descriptors in terms of other class properties.  More below:

The implementation iterates through all the keys of `descriptors` when the constructor is called, and for each such key `k`, it defines a property on `this` with the key `k`, and the property descriptor that comes out when you call `descriptors[k]`.

Note that the compiler cannot verify that the implementation matches the call signature, for the same reasons that it cannot verify your original example; we have not declared the properties and `Object.defineProperty()` has not been seen to initialize them.  That's why the returned `class` has been [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `as any`.  This suppresses any warnings about the class implementation, so we have to be careful that the implementation and call signature match.

But anyway, once we have `ClassFromDescriptorFactories()`, we can use it multiple times.

---

For your color palette example, you can make a general-purpose `colorDescriptor()` function which takes an `initValue` string input, and which produces a no-arg function which produces a property descriptor with the validation you want:

```
function colorDescriptor(initValue: string) {
    return () => {
        let value = initValue;
        return {
            enumerable: true,
            get() { return value },
            set(hex: string) {
                if (/^#[0-9a-f]{6}$/i.test(hex)) {
                    value = hex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `value` variable is used to store the actual string value of the color.  The whole point of the indirection `() => {...}` is so that each instance of the eventual class has its *own* `value` variable;  Otherwise, you'd end up having `value` be a static property of the class, which you don't want.

And now we can use it with `ClassFromDescriptorFactories()` to define `ColorPalette`:

```
class ColorPalette extends ClassFromDescriptorFactories({
    foregroundColor: colorDescriptor("#cccccc"),
    backgroundColor: colorDescriptor("#333333"),
    borderColor: colorDescriptor("#aaaaaa"),
}) {
    toString(): string {
        return Object.values(this).map(c => c.toString().toUpperCase()).join(", ");
    }
}
```

This compiles without error, and the compiler recognizes instances of `ColorPalette` as having `string`-valued properties at keys `foregroundColor`, `backgroundColor`, and `borderColor`, and at runtime these properties have the proper validation:

```
let redPalette = new ColorPalette();

redPalette.foregroundColor = "#ff0000";
console.log(redPalette.toString()); // "#FF0000, #333333, #AAAAAA" 

redPalette.backgroundColor = "oopsie";
console.log(redPalette.backgroundColor) // still #333333
```

And just to make sure each instance has its own properties, let's create a new instance:

```
let bluePalette = new ColorPalette();
bluePalette.foregroundColor = "#0000ff";
console.log(redPalette.foregroundColor) // #ff0000
console.log(bluePalette.foregroundColor) // #0000ff
```

Yeah, `bluePalette` and `redPalette` don't share a common `foregroundColor` property.  Looks good!

---

Note the `ThisType<T>` code comes in handy in situations like this, where we are adding a new descriptor that refers to other properties of the class:

```
class ColorPalette extends ClassFromDescriptorFactories({
    foregroundColor: colorDescriptor("#cccccc"),
    backgroundColor: colorDescriptor("#333333"),
    borderColor: colorDescriptor("#aaaaaa"),
    foregroundColorNumber() {
        const that = this;
        const descriptor = {
            get() {
                return Number.parseInt(that.foregroundColor.slice(1), 16);
            }
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}) {
    toString(): string {
        return Object.values(this).map(c => c.toString().toUpperCase()).join(", ");
    }
}
```

Here the compiler understands that `foregroundColorNumber()` is defining a `number` property on `T`, and that the `this` inside the implementation corresponds to `T`, and thus calls like the following work without error:

```
console.log("0x" + redPalette.foregroundColorNumber.toString(16)) // 0xff0000
console.log(redPalette.foregroundColor = "#000000")
console.log("0x" + redPalette.foregroundColorNumber.toString(16)) // 0x0
```

If you remove `ThisType<T>`, you will see some errors show up.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Cgkil4AbEKKJAYQHtTa0AFEUiAF3eQON6QDNGELGloBXYABM6DNAEIAXEijtMwLAG5CfIgCMEAaxHipMxouWqM6rTr2NJENGflKVazdp0BiePUZUALxIANpedkQhAESCaMKiEtL+aFEANEhRvvDZ2VEAuqnhEdH68EYJpslpGd4AzPUN+YURvCUOTi7VmSA9vflFxHlaA0R+wO5i8OyMABQAlHgjfOwAFhhQAHS+yZuxAKIIKzMzEOkYC4EAfIstdii6AFYQUxuO-NYQTKIwTuwAnjNVut0kDNttZFAQhg8iEAAwFG63FoQYBiSBoEC6NhKVRiU5LJFILAceZ4JBxdhiNDAJCgrZ+CFQmEARiGSAAvs1CXYoCSVhAAB5uKzqBY8bm3DD8JAzAD0AD1vHCALQAThAyv4eVwADZ2QASWUYDZcFQzfkCuZigkS5ZrMEMgJMkKspDBC22W0Rdk224+r3sua+jlzT06H1LaYAZRFWHmwo8iNuFKpNPuTxeADdWHioID7XMNmAQDAZvA3dd4CbaDGPPNqwBVGA-ZwUCDzQsPWjWGZdUNLf3EQdENjsckQSQsUdcN1IYAQADuNGSU44XHmYfHk9Ya4gG1i8RMSVks8y-H4sMvsKim7GUHoe4Ycbi2+ne+jsY7Wgj-AkUwwtA0tQ5CUAAYqIYAACLQPAmAwNMaCgQgCEYNAAA8AAqSCClwUhULQjzPOwlwzI4UCwRg8EBEoGH2hhfw-Jh1wAGThLgoQANJINYSAGBAfy0NKGF5Eo+brDRFzXPRPyTt8vx-NB5FwQhmEhBxeTXIGSjzkupJXEgWHikQKbUiQIFUEZfB3riUyzNahKjrxSh8QJQmbhEsQygY3E0mRFFUWgUD2ba6ZEa8EDvPOXy0C2-xiVA6QGOkpEwcpARIBQGXAH8cwhAYeQbPArCkPFVrBsOfAVeyGVUCA2XfvgjW-sA-6ASQySKf5CEzNYGDsAAajmEAJtYWDBcZHCpjKklJnwjnZqQeKzr1A1De5xAmTSlkRCiaJOJi2K0mgeJcrcxLsKS7GbUgC1LZywa8hdFojaKs2ElKMoKkqsJqhqWq6gaRomtAT2Clab22rdyDuoK61+uVA7hD6EZkBQVAuKunDIDhKKSOj5ngbQUGpZRCFIbZmDQDMlkHsYiQuEojpoJ1aVoL2WQ5PAURzKdSClOUR4M+1sgs6TsyZA0jQ8+EujtM4ySMx1JMBezvR9NLvC0xUx6MAAcmiuhOJdSzWbSKwgGOwSgnD7XjGOfms7O212Odxtetd+tgIbaAbHAgUQAAksAF2rBb+5CHTlSyBsUCkBgiAzMyPNIMyOr9oSFW8JnG2TaZDti2gm7I+NtI1p+cwvTgzsTZSpmhVmQ15qChbFqW5b6VWH51oW0xNi21Bth2Gxdj2fZF-gEaOS+mMzsEOnLrIM-tv2+DTzuWPh3Ekc62gp7eOeV7Xlod4PhsT4zGvb7VrWo1fkgsqyjUoGgYf6R1JLtRvwAgj-v9REgjVL67g2PzbeLhTy0BilAVCN58AnzYGfWgz4JxLxAYYMByQFgP0sBgUgpAkDv0lo1RyWI8RL1nPPDG691z9lIZ8ahe4taC2SHvQ+55YHwMfEgi+KCGGb0PPTTB99H77wvFeOBgF7wIPPnQ1BTDBGyCwSIth-BGoSPGKfc+URYQCn-gAai3HIiO2sXCe29tfT8qdwbYJ0QfcRnDEHINfMA+RUdGCsMPteIMDitE6P0YYvhrid5mKcBYusVilFIB0bCfAQA)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I don't get what's the importance of `ThisType<T>` in `ClassFromDescriptorFactories` function.  There's no errors when I remove that, and everything seems working fine. I'll get an error if I remove `ThisType` in [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) example from the docs. Also, when I put `console.log(this.constructor.name)` inside the constructor function it prints `ColorPalette`, but the passed object is not of type `ColorPalette`. To my understanding `ThisType<T>` is not needed here, am I missing something?

Comment: The `ThisType` thing would be useful if you have inline descriptors to help inference, but is not necessary. Let me look when I get a chance to see if there’s a situation where it makes a difference in that code

Comment: Added some stuff about `ThisType` (but I did notice a bug that was not allowing the `this` from the class instance to apply properly, and I fixed that too).